# how to show single and multiple checkbox on select dropdown, parse value to checkbox on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have three DIV's The first DIV is a dropdown select DIV with one, multiple, and none.

**What I want:**

1. On the "one" selection I want it to display a checkbox in the third DIV to let users check only one checkbox and on "multiple" select I want it to display only checkbox with multiple select, and on "none" selection I want it to display a checkbox in the third DIV to let users check only one checkbox.
2. Lastly, in the second DIV, I have a select dropdown with javascript value and list of arrays I want when any dropdown is selected it should parse a list of value to checkbox in the third DIV

```
<!------- First DIV -------->
<div>
                        <label for="sampleRecipientInput">How many physical locations you have *</label>
                        <div class="ss-custom-select">
                            <select class="full-width" id="blocation" name="blocation">
                                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the number of physical location</option>
                                
                                <option value="One">One</option>
                                <option value="Multiple">Multiple</option>
                                <option value="Online">None (ex. online only)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>  
                            <p id = "displayLocationError" style="color: red"></p>                  
                 
                                            
                  </div>



                  <script type="text/javascript">

                    var subtypeLists = new Array(4);
 subtypeLists["empty"] = ["Select the subtype of business"]; 

 subtypeLists["Ball Sports"] = ["Football", "Basketball", "Volleyball","Tennis", "Cricket", "Bowling","American Football", "Ruby", "Handball","Water Polo", "Golf"]; 

 subtypeLists["Extreme Sports"] = ["Skydiving", "Zipline", "Bungee Jumping", "Air Tunnel","Dune Bashing", "Parasailing", "Parkour", "Gliding"]; 

 subtypeLists["Entertainment"] = ["Thrill Parks", "VR Parks", "Haunted House","Paintball", "Karoake", "Stand Up","Animal Interaction", "Safari", "Aquarium", "Experience"]; 

 subtypeLists["Motorized Sports"]= ["Karting", "ATV & Motor Rentals", "Track Racing", "Dirt Biking"]; 

 subtypeLists["Aquatic Sports"]= ["Watercrafts", "Surfing", "Swimming", "Wakeboarding", "Scubadiving", "Fishing"]; 
 
 subtypeLists["Skills"]= ["Art & Crafts", "Equestrian", "Falconry", "Archery", "Music Lessons", "Chess Lessons", "General Workshops"]; 
 
 subtypeLists["Strength & Agility"]= ["Martial Arts", "Fitness", "Dancing", "Strength", "Fencing"]; 
 
 subtypeLists["Kids"]= ["Educational Workshops", "Fun & Adventure Experience", "Story Telling", "Overall hobbies for kids"]; 
 
                    
                     function categoryChange(selectObj) { 
 // get the index of the selected option 
 var idx = selectObj.selectedIndex; 
 // get the value of the selected option 
 var which = selectObj.options[idx].value; 
 // use the selected option value to retrieve the list of items from the subtypeLists array 
 cList = subtypeLists[which]; 
 // get the country select element via its known id 
 var cSelect = document.getElementById("subtype"); 
 // remove the current options from the country select 
 var len=cSelect.options.length; 
 while (cSelect.options.length > 0) { 
 cSelect.remove(0); 
 } 
 var newOption; 
 // create new options 
 for (var i=0; i<cList.length; i++) { 
 newOption = document.createElement("option"); 
 newOption.value = cList[i];  // assumes option string and value are the same 
 newOption.text=cList[i]; 
 // add the new option 
 try { 
 cSelect.add(newOption);  // this will fail in DOM browsers but is needed for IE 
 } 
 catch (e) { 
 cSelect.appendChild(newOption); 
 } 
 } 
 } 

                  </script>


<!----- Second DIV ------->
                  <div>
                        <label for="sampleRecipientInput">Type of business?</label>
                        <div class="ss-custom-select">
                            <select class="full-width" id="btype" name="btype" onchange="categoryChange(this);">
                                
                                <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select the type of business</option>
                                <option value="Ball Sports">Ball Sports</option>
                                <option value="Extreme Sports">Extreme Sports</option>
                                <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                                <option value="Motorized Sports">Motorized Sports</option>
                                <option value="Aquatic Sports">Aquatic Sports</option>
                                <option value="Skills">Skills</option>
                                <option value="Strength & Agility">Strength & Agility</option>
                                <option value="Kids">Kids</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>      
                            <p id = "displayTypeError" style="color: red"></p>                  
                                
                  </div>


<!----- Third DIV ----->
                  <div>
                        <label for="sampleRecipientInput">Subtype of business?</label>
                        <div class="ss-custom-select">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="full-width" id="subtype" name="subtype[]" multiple="multiple" value="">
                                
                                    </input>
                        </div>      
                            <p id = "displaySubTypeError" style="color: red"></p>                   
                                
                  </div>
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your code?  In other words, at what point is your code not doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: 1. On the "one" selection I want it to display a checkbox in the third DIV to let users check only one checkbox and on "multiple" select I want it to display only checkbox with multiple select, and on "none" selection I want it to display a checkbox in the third DIV to let users check only one checkbox.

2. Lastly, in the second DIV, I have a select dropdown with javascript value and list of arrays I want when any dropdown is selected it should parse a list of value to checkbox in the third DIV

Comment: You should break your requirements down into small tasks.  Research how to do that one specific task, and when you reach a point where your code isn't giving you the results you need, post a question about that one small task, include your code, and tell us how that code isn't giving you the results you expect.  What you currently have posted is more like a job description looking for someone to hire to do work.  This site isn't free coding services.  Show us your effort to resolve the problem yourself and we'll help you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the wrapping elements in javascript and manipulate the dom.  Some functions you want to look up is document.CreateElement(), element.setAttribute(), and parentNode.append().

Comment: Can you please do this for me with the code I have above? I am kind of new to javascript.